# Error while installing Microsoft SharePoint 2010 on Windows 7 machine

Tags: sharepoint, windows-7, sharepoint-2010

I've installed Microsoft SharePoint 2010 on my Windows 7 64bits machine. I've modified the config.xml file to accomplish this.

Once it's installed I run the Configuration Wizard to create a new site and it throws me the following exception:

> An exception of type
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException was
>   thrown.  Additional exception
>   information: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could
>   not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.IdentityModel,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified. File
>   name: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.CurrentUserIsAdministrator(Boolean
>   allowContentApplicationAccess)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPPersistedStoreProvider.DoesCurrentUserHaveWritePermission(SPPersistedObject
>   persistedObject)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.BaseUpdate()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Update()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.RegisterDefaultDatabaseServices(SqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   connectionString)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.Provision(SqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   connectionString)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Create(SqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   configurationDatabase,
>   SqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   administrationContentDatabase,
>   IdentityType identityType, String
>   farmUser, SecureString farmPassword,
>   SecureString masterPassphrase)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.CreateOrConnectConfigDb()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.Run()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

Note: I don't have the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 64bits installed, but SharePoint 2010 seems that installed its necessary components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by taking the following steps:

1.) "Re-installing" the WCF Activation Fix that you should have installed as a pre-requisite. It should tell you that you already have this installed.

2.) Rerun the Config Wizard.

No idea why this worked, but it did.

**I would also verify that .NET is installed correctly and that it is configured correctly for use in IIS.

Comment: I'm sorry. Where should I get WCF Activation Fix from?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem before but it gives me the file not found exception about this assembly : Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

i installed the Windows Identity Foundation and solved my problem.
here is the [link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=eb9c345f-e830-40b8-a5fe-ae7a864c4d76&displaylang=en)

Comment: Yes. this is the fix for it. Install the download form the above link and continue.....